# Passing hardware register pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, avr

I'm poking around with xMega AVR microcontroller, and having trouble passing the hardware register as a pointer. Pretty sure this is pointer magic, but after a long day can't understand what's wrong.

`PORTA` is defined (in GCC-AVR toolchain) as follows:

```
#define PORTA (*(PORT_t *) 0x0600)
```

This works:

```
int main(void)
{
    // This will set GPIO high
    PORTA.DIRSET = 1 << 1;
    PORTA.OUTSET = 1 << 1;

    while(1) {};
}
```

And this won't work:

```
void gpio_output_set(PORT_t * port, unsigned char pin)
{
    // This will *NOT* set GPIO high
    port->DIRSET = 1 << pin;
    port->OUTSET = 1 << pin;
}

int main(void)
{
    gpio_output_set(&PORTA, 1);

    while(1) {};
}
```

Why?

Comment: Please explain what you exactly mean by "this won't work", so **edit your question** again.

Comment: But your edit is not enough. What exactly is not working? How did you compile your code? Did you look into the generated assembler code (`gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O`)

Comment: GPIO is not set high, as I already wrote. No, I haven't looked into assembly.

Comment: for starters you need to post the structure PORT_t definition.  then of course the disassembly of the produced code.

Comment: I am confused. In my opinion that should work. I have my own library where I use it that way and the Atmel Framework libraries do it as well.

Comment: Was an explanation ever found for this ? @Rev1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it should work.

Essentially it the same as

```
PORT_t* pPort = &*(PORT_t*)0x0600;
pPort->DIRSET = 0x01;
```

So why should this be a problem? The Atmel Software Framework libraries use this as well:

```
void PORT_ConfigureInterrupt0(PORT_t* port, PORT_INT0LVL_t intLevel, uint8_t pinMask);

PORT_ConfigureInterrupt0(&PORTC, PORT_INT0LVL_MED_gc, 0x01);
```

Comment: You're right. There was a bug in my code, but I do not remember details anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should have

```
  #define PORTA ((PORT_t *) 0x0600)
```

<sup>(no initial `*` before the cast!)</sup>

then replace your `set` line with something like

```
gpio_output_set(PORTA, (unsigned char)10);
```

Comment: I will not redefine PORTA, since this line was ripped from GCC-AVR toolchain includes.

Comment: You will need to define a new constant or macro: `#define PORTA_ADDRESS ((PORT_t *) 0x600)`.  The problem is that AVR's macro is *reading* from the port; it doesn't represent the port's address.  This is one example of why I prefer to write my own SDK rather than use a vendor's.  Making the pass MISRA and static analyzers are other reasons.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: No, the macro doesn't _read_ from the port. As the first working example shows, the same macro also is used to write to the port. And this is possible, because the macro _does_ represent the port's address (0x600)